# Why do I encounter data inconsistency when reading a static variable in a worker thread?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I added a variable to a static array in the main thread, but I found the array to be empty when operating on it in a worker thread. What could be the issue, and how can it be resolved?

Event_queue is a queue which store the event triggered, EventHandler is a class which handle the event(by EventHandler.handle()), EventManager is a class which work to register(by EventManager.install()) the event.
My method is: When EventListener.trigger() the event, EventHandler.add() will add the event into the context.event_queue. Then, EventListener.listen() will notice the event_queue has event to handle and EventListener.listen() will invoke EventHandler.handle() to handle the event.

I was listen a variable in EventListener.js

```
// EventListener.js
// context.event_queue is the variable i watched
import context from "./EUEventContext.js";

export default class EventListener{
static listen() {
        setInterval(() => {
            // console.log('listening');
            if (context.event_queue.isEmpty() === false) {
                const e = context.event_queue.deque()
                if (e !== null)
                    EventHandler.handle(e)
            }
        }, 200);
    }
}

// func trigger will add a element into the context.event_queue
static trigger(event: Event) {
        EventHandler.add(event)
    }
```

the thead based on ListenerThread.js

```
// ListenerThread.js

EventListener.listen()
```

this is my main.js, i tried to trigger a event

```
const worker = new Worker(listener_path)
console.log(listener_path)


const e =  new Event("test_event")
console.log(e.name)
EventManager.install(e)
EventManager.on(e, () => {
    console.log("Hello World!")
})
setTimeout(()=>{
    EventListener.trigger(e)
}, 2000)
```

this is the context.event_queue

```
// EventContext.js
export default class EventContext {
private static _queue: Queue<Event> = new Queue<Event>();

    static get event_queue() {
        return this._queue;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show some code?

Comment: of cause, i'v add the code.

Comment: this is a simple event system and i want to listen event in a thread.

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. What are `context.event_queue`, `EventHandler`, `EventManager`? Where do you actually send the event to the `worker`?

Comment: event_queue is a queue which store the event triggered,
EventHandler is a class which handle the event(by EventHandler.handle()),
EventManager is a class which work to register(by EventManager.install()) the event.

Comment: My method is:
When EventListener.trigger() the event, EventHandler.add() will add the event into the context.event_queue. Then, EventListener.listen() will notice the event_queue has event to handle and  EventListener.listen() will invoke EventHandler.handle() to handle the event.

Comment: Since you still haven't shown the part where you send anything to the `worker`, it sounds like your problem is a fundamental misunderstanding of how web workers work in JS: they do not share any memory. Is that what you expected "static variables" to do? All communication between workers needs to go through messages (via `.postMessage()`, you do not need to build your own event system.